# Can't log in to Outlook POP server using ASP.NET TcpClient - invalid credentials

Tags: asp.net, outlook, tcpclient, pop3

After midnight I started getting error when trying to connect to Outlook POP server from ASP.NET application using TcpClient with SSL. I'm receiving an OK response from the POP server and then it responds with "-ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.". However the credentials are corrent and I'm able to log in to the account using the same user name and password through the browser.

I can see there were some changes implemented today to block older versions of outlook, which probably affected me in some way as well. Have anyone had a similar issue with this and has a possible solution?

POP settings I'm using:
Server name: outlook.office365.com
Port: 995

Comment: Why are you using TcpClient instead of an email client like MailKit? And why POP3 instead of IMAP? Mailkit has a [sample](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md) that shows how to connect to Outlook Online using OAuth2 and POP3, IMAP or SMTP

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's an old application from years ago and it was implemented this way there.

Answer (score 2):

Office365 has just started requiring OAuth2.0 authentication for SMTP, POP3, and IMAP.

You cannot use a username and password anymore.

Comment: You should probably say "just discontinued". So has GMail. Basic authentication is simply to insecure. I'm not sure if corporate accounts can re-enable basic, in either service. As a developer I'd rather not find out, but switch all applications to finally use OAuth